# Why does this nested for loop loops infinitely (java)?

Tags: java, nested-loops, infinite-loop

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);

            for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're reusing the counter

Comment: use a different variable for the counter of your inner loop

Answer (score 6):

You are using the same loop variable `i` for both the outer and the inner loops.

The inner loop resets `i` to `0` and increments it to `1`, and then the outer loop increments it to `2`, but it can never get higher than `2` (since the next time the inner loop executes, it will be reset to `0` again), so the outer loop never ends.

Use a different variable for the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'm a starter. didn't knew the inner loop resets i.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner for loop has same variable use that is used in your outer for loop so  it goes to infinite loop, make change on inner for loop just put `int` front of `j`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    System.out.println(j);
}
```